# Does kinetic energy change for every point of the motion of a object that moves from point A to B?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, energy, kinematics

Does a moving object have changing kinetic energy? If it is the case, does the maximum kinetic energy equals potential energy?

Comment: What do you think?

Answer (score 1):

Kinetic energy is only dependent on mass and velocity $Ke=(1/2)mv^2$. If a moving object moves with constant velocity then it's kinetic energy doesn't change. Any objects maximum kinetic energy is obtained when that objects velocity is greatest. In the case of an object in free fall starting from rest then it's kinetic energy is always increasing and its maximum kinetic entry will be given by the objects initial gravitational potential energy.